# Get last transaction per product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have typical order header and order line tables.
This is the simplified DDL (there are more fields, but not important for this question)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderHeader](
    [id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [voucherDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [voucherNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [voucherType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [account] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [po] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [total] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [discount] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [rounding] [decimal](19, 3) NULL,
    [net] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [warehouse] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderLine](
    [header] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [line] [int] NOT NULL,
    [item] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [quantity] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [price] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [discount] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
    [total] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderLine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [header] ASC,
    [line] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to run a query in sql server where it returns in each warehouse, the last order line per item.

so

```
warehouse 1
       item1, Order20, line 3
       item2, Order 40, line 1

   warehouse 2
        item1, Order25, line 1
```

etc...

multiple orders in the same warehouse could exist on the same date for the same item, in this case it needs to be the latest order. I am not using DateTime for orderDate, it's just a date.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried yourself writing a query yet?  I ask this not only because it is really expected on SO, but because it would my job of getting you an answer much easier.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

Without usable Sample data, or DDL, this is a guess. If it doesn't work, please edit your post and reply to this answer.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT OH.Warehouse,
           OL.Item,
           OH.OrderNbr,
           OH.LineNbr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OH.Warehouse, OL.LineNbr ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RN
    FROM OrderHeader OH
         JOIN OrderLine OL ON OH.OrderNbr = OL.OrderHbr)
SELECT Warehouse,
       Item,
       OrderNbr,
       LineNbr
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Note that you haven't defined how to determine what is the latest order if they are on the same day, thus I haven't considered it. You'll need to edit the `ORDER BY` to ensure it works for your data if that is the problem (or, again, edit your post).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I added the DDL of the tables. I guess to tell what is the latest order, I need to go by voucherDate and voucherNumber

Comment: @daoud175 Without sample data and expected results for that DDL, that doesn't tell me much more. Have you tried what I provided? As I said, you'll likely need to add a little more to the `ORDER BY`, but I imagine this gets your on the right track.

Comment: yes I tried. the same item/warehouse combination is showing multiple time. shouldn't be getting max(orderDate) ?